# Error en Trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema No funciona este código. Me salta este error #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 6

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_MORA
AFTER INSERT on servicios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO deteconomico(FECHA_PAGAR)
VALUES(NEW.FECHA_PAG);
```

Answer (score -1):

Falta la palabra "END". al final del query